# SQL query to JSON data

Tags: json, sql-server

We've JSON entry in the MS SQL database. I would like to export JSON entry in the "Data" column which match with the list of EMPNO. Could someone please help?

ColumnName: `Data`

Data inside the column:

```
output:{
   "Request":{
      "Person":{
         "DisplayName":"Test User",
         "EMPNO":"000001",
         "Entity":"01",
         "Country":"AA"
      },
      "DomainOverride":null,
      "ReasonForGen":"Only",
      "Email":"123@test.com",
      "CurrentSIP":"123@test.com"
   },
   "EmailAddress":"123@testcom",
   "SIPAddress":"123@test.com",
   "Status":"NoChange"
}
```

Query in layman language:

```sql
select DisplayName,EMPNO,Entity,Country,DomainOverride,ReasonForGen,Email
from Table1
where data.output.Request.EMPNO in ([EMPNO list])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Something like this:

```
select JSON_VALUE(data,'$.Output.Request.Person.DisplayName'), ...
from Table1
where JSON_VALUE(data,'$.Output.Request.Person.EMPNO') in ([EMPNO list])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `OPENJSON()` to parse the JSON text and get objects and values from the JSON input as a table. You need to use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema in the `WITH` clause to define the columns:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   JsonData nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Data 
   (JsonData)
VALUES
   (N'{
   "output":{
      "Request":{
         "Person":{
            "DisplayName":"Test User",
            "EMPNO":"000001",
            "Entity":"01",
            "Country":"AA"
         },
         "DomainOverride":null,
         "ReasonForGen":"Only",
         "Email":"123@test.com",
         "CurrentSIP":"123@test.com"
      },
      "EmailAddress":"123@testcom",
      "SIPAddress":"123@test.com",
      "Status":"NoChange"
   }
}')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
   j.DisplayName,
   j.EMPNO,
   j.Entity,
   j.Country,
   j.DomainOverride,
   j.ReasonForGen,
   j.Email
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonData) WITH (
   EMPNO nvarchar(10) '$.output.Request.Person.EMPNO',
   DisplayName nvarchar(50) '$.output.Request.Person.DisplayName',
   EMPNO nvarchar(50) '$.output.Request.Person.EMPNO',
   Entity nvarchar(50) '$.output.Request.Person.Entity',
   Country nvarchar(50) '$.output.Request.Person.Country',
   DomainOverride nvarchar(50) '$.output.Request.DomainOverride',
   ReasonForGen nvarchar(50) '$.output.Request.ReasonForGen',
   Email nvarchar(50) '$.output.Request.Email'
) j
-- Use additional WHERE clause
--WHERE j.EMPNO IN ('00001', '000002')
```

Result:

```
DisplayName EMPNO   Entity  Country DomainOverride  ReasonForGen    Email
Test User   000001  01      AA                      Only            123@test.com
```